# how to fire an event when seek bar reaches a particular time in streaming in android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a surface view , and a media player to stream the video.
Say after 10 sec , I need to make a particular layout visible.
For that is there any event which can constantly monitor the progress of seek bar and fire an event at appropriate time?

Explanation in detail:
Say I have a video of 10mins being played.
At the end of 10th second , a layout should be made visible in the view.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at OnSeekBarChangeListener#OnProgressChange
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html

Another way is to write a Handler monitoring the current position of the video then set the view to be visible when current position is more than 10 sec. Stop the handler after that.

```
VideoTimerHandler videoTimerHandler = new VideoTimerHandler();
videoTimerHandler.playVideoTimer();

// Handler that monitor video progress every 1 sec
private class VideoTimerHandler extends Handler {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoTimerHandler";

    private final int VIDEO_TIMER_PERIOD = 1000;

    public void playVideoTimer(){
        this.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    public void stopVideoTimer(){
        this.removeMessages(0);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        if (player.getCurrentPosition() > 10){
            yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            // check again after 1 sec
            this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, VIDEO_TIMER_PERIOD);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you pls elaborate in code for the second part pls..i'm a newbie here. Thanks

Comment: onseekbarchangelistener is called only when the user changes the seek bar, but for me, the moment 10th second is reached, an event should be fired

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

Why don't you want to use the MediaPlayer associated with your SeekBar? MediaPlayer exposes an onCompletion callback:

```
OnCompletionListener cListener = new OnCompletionListener(){

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        //do something
    }
};

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(cListener);
```

**Second Method**

You should use `Handler's postDelayed` function for this purpose. It will run your code with specified delay on the `main UI thread`, so you will be able to update UI controls.

```
    private int mInterval = 10*1000; // 10 seconds by default,or calculate it mediaplayer.getDuration(); //it is in milliseconds

      private Handler mHandler;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        ...
        mHandler = new Handler();
      }

      Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
          showDesireLayout(); //change visibility in this function.
          //mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval); //uncomment it if you want to repeat it after equal intervals of time.
        }
      };

      void startRepeatingTask() {
        mStatusChecker.run(); 
      }

      void stopRepeatingTask() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
      }
```

Just call `startRepeatingTask();`